# Is there anyway to convert svg string to jsx string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I've svg jsx components that i want as string so i can copy it. on the website i'm working on, i've provided two options to copy the svg element. one i achieved by using `renderToString` function from `react-dom/server`, that gives me svg string, and other one i want as jsx component string,

the component

```js
const SvgComponent1 = (props) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width={100}
    height={100}
    fill="none"
    {...props}
  >
    <path
      fill="#D9D9D9"
      stroke="#000"
      strokeWidth={5}
      d="M2.5 2.5h95v95h-95z"
    />
  </svg>
)
```

renderToString function result

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" fill="none"><path fill="#D9D9D9" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" d="M2.5 2.5h95v95h-95z"></path></svg>
```

is this possible to convert this svg string back to the jsx string, similar to [svgr playground](https://react-svgr.com/playground/) at runtime? do i have to store the string version with the jsx code, not possible at runtime? i have many svgs.

Comment: You can use the `svgr` on the runtime. The tool of the playground you mentioned.